# Can samba authentication be coupled to file encryption? What about WebDAV?

Tags: linux, windows, samba, encryption, webdav

I'd like my NAS ([Buffalo LinkStation Pro](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/network-storage/home-and-small-office-nas/linkstation-pro-duo-1) running Linux 2.6.31.8 #1 Fri Jun 8 11:07:30 JST 2012 armv5tel GNU/Linux) to share an encrypted filesystem to the Windows clients as transparently as possible. Currently, I have too SSH into the NAS and manually mount/unmount the directory. Is it somehow possible to instead simply couple the samba authentication mechanism to the mounting of the encrypted filesystem? Or should I rather try and get samba 4 to run, which seems to support NTFS encryption? Or WebDAV?